# After some jobs on the branch and git push origin (branch name), I did 'git checkout origin main', instead of

Tags: git

'git checkout origin'. after this, (HEAD detached at 08d4d2f) poped up like below;

```
C:\Users\sung\proj\easy (HEAD detached at 08d4d2f)
```

after checking the content of '08d4d2f', I did 'git reset --hard HEAD@{15}' , which is right before 08d4d2f. even after I have done 'reset --hard' command, (HEAD detached at 08d4d2f) does not disappear

```
C:\Users\sung\proj\easy (HEAD detached at 08d4d2f)
```

I would like to go back to normal... getting rid of this message 'HEAD detached at 08d4d2f

Plus is there anyway to clean the history? I tried to do many things to get rid of that message so now the history is not clean, when I checked 'git reflog'.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+Git+detached+head

Comment: I think you actually ran `git checkout origin`. This meant `git checkout origin/main`. Both of these result in this detached-HEAD condition you mention. Meanwhile: one question per question, if possible; the main question here is a duplicate.